# Let $G = \langle a\rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $15$, and let $f : G \to G$ be the map defined by $f(g) = g^5$. Is f an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Task is:

> Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $15$, and let $f \colon G \rightarrow G$ be the map defined by $f(g) = g^5$.
> Is $f$ an isomorphism?

Intuitively, I think the group fails the condition of bijectivity as I consider integers mod $15$ under addition. If the group $G$ is cyclic and of order $15$, it should be isomorphic to integers mod $15$ under addition, no?

***Edit for those looking this up :*** $G$ being cyclic has a generator a whose order is $15$. $f(a^3)=f(e)=e$, so $f$ is not one-one, hence not an isomorphism.
Answer by  @Anurag A with helpful comments from others.

Comment: Yes, a cyclic group of order $15$ is isomorphic to integers mod $15$ under addition

Comment: Hence, i am correct in assuming the map is not bijective, and therefore not isomorphic?

Comment: Hint: calculate the order of elements in the image.

Comment: I did. Again testing with some examples with integers mod 15 under addition seems to point that it is isomorphic. I just have no idea how that connects with the orders of the elements. Order of most elements is 3.

Comment: $G$ being cyclic has a generator $a$ whose order is $15$. $f(a^3)=f(e)=e$, so $f$ is not one-one, hence not an isomorphism.

Comment: Is there an element in the image of $f$ that has order greater than $3$?  If not, what conclusion can you draw?

Comment: The $n$th power map is an automorphism of a finite abelian group $A$ if and only if $n$ is coprime to the order of $A$. Also, $5$ and $15$ are not coprime.

Comment: Ahaa, i see. Thank you! It was probably a stupid question but im pretty horrible at this, so thanks for dealing with it. I understand!

Answer (score 1):

Cyclic should already be a big hint. $a$ has order 15, and the exponent is 5. 15/5=3, so $$f(a^3)=a^{15}=1_G=1_G^5=f(1_G)$$, where $1_G$ is the identity of $G$.